# How can I print methods name in my class

Tags: python, class, methods

for example:

```
class Employee:
   'Common base class for all employees'
   empCount = 0

   def __init__(self, name, salary):
      self.name = name
      self.salary = salary
      Employee.empCount += 1

   def displayCount(self):
     print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount

   def displayEmployee(self):
      print "Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary
```

I want to print the methods name.
The output should  be like:

```
Class Employee contains (displayCount,displayEmployee)
```

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This gets *all* method names:

```
import inspect
methodnames = [name for name,member in inspect.getmembers(Employee) if inspect.ismethod(member)]
```

...and this does the same but excludes method names like `__init__` that start with `__`:

```
import inspect
methodnames = [name for name,member in inspect.getmembers(Employee) if inspect.ismethod(member) and not name.startswith('__')]
```

In the second version, `methodnames` will be `['displayCount', 'displayEmployee']`.